# Adjust div opacity upon scroll with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, opacity

I've read several suggestions on how to do this, but I can't find one that covers how to change the opacity once it reaches an offset on the page AND animate the change. Also keep in mind that I don't want to completely fade out the div, just cut the opacity by half once the user scrolls past a certain point.

I came up with this, but I can't figure out how to properly animate the change in opacity:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fadeStart=150 
,fading = $('#header')
;

$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
var offset = $(document).scrollTop()
;
if( offset<=fadeStart ){
    opacity=1;
}else if( offset>=fadeStart ){
    opacity=0.5;
}
fading.css('opacity',opacity);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the final value at one using `fading.css('opacity',opacity);`, animate it by using `fading.animate({opacity: opacity}, 'fast');`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can edit with this:

```
var fadeStart=150
    ,fading = $('#header')
;

$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    var offset = $(document).scrollTop()
        ,opacity=0
    ;
    if( offset<=fadeStart ){
        opacity=1;
    }else if( offset<=fadeUntil ){
        opacity=1-offset/fadeUntil;
    }
    fading.css('opacity',opacity)//.html(opacity)
    ;
});
```